# Unable to open .xlsx file after 'pd.to_excel'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a .xlsx file from 2 lists:
`list_of_aliases` which is the sheet names.
`list_of_dfs` which is the list of dataframes.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test_file.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
for sheet_name, df in zip(list_of_aliases, list_of_dfs):
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)
```

The code runs without errors, but the final .xlsx file is 0 kb and I get the error:
"Excel cannot open the file 'test_file.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."

The dataframes are around 50 rows and 4 columns, don't contain special characters, and some of the strings a a few sentences long, so I don't believe this is an issue with the contents of the dataframes themselves.

Comment: 0kB file sounds to me like you're generating the data, but it's in a buffer somewhere and not actually flushed to disk. Check that you're properly closing your resources.

Comment: Use `with` with writer, so the file will be flushed properly. Else you should care to close the writer.

Answer (score 0):

closing the writer fixed this. ty